# convertion number using vlook up microsoft excel

Tags: excel, ms-word

How to convert number to letters for example i input 9 i want the output is nine but the output is N/A

[image]

This is my another sheet

[image]

Is it possible ?

Answer (score 0):

You won't be able to do this with Vlookup, since that formula will try to find the input value in the first column.

If you input the number 9 into cell A33 on the other sheet, you can use this formula:

```
=if(A33<10,index(Words!$A$3:$A$11,A33),"")
```